# Can AdomdConnection accept a token

Tags: c#, azure, azure-analysis-services

I have the following code to gain access to SQL using C#, is there an equivalent for analysis services?  I've tried different approaches but I can't see where you can provide an access token?

**Create SQL connection**

```
return new SqlConnection($"Data Source=abc; Initial Catalog=def")
{
    AccessToken = GetToken()
};
```

**Analysis Services connection**

```
var builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
{
    ConnectionString = "abc"
};

builder.Add("Password", "5r6utviub");

return new AdomdConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
```

**The GetToken method is below**

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("xxx");
        request.Headers["Metadata"] = "true";
        request.Method = "GET";
        string accessToken;
        try
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var streamResponse = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string stringResponse = streamResponse.ReadToEnd();
            JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var list = (Dictionary<string, string>)j.Deserialize(stringResponse, typeof(Dictionary<string, string>));
            accessToken = list["access_token"];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
        return accessToken;
```

**Update**

```
var builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
{
    ConnectionString = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=asazure://somewhere.asazure.windows.net/xyz;Catalog=mydb;Password={GetToken()};Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate"
};
return new AdomdConnection(builder.ConnectionString);

conn.Open();  // fails with Authentication failed
```

**Update #2 - shows the connection string**

```
Provider=MSOLAP;
Data Source=asazure://somewhere.asazure.windows.net/xyz;
Persist Security Info=True;
Password=qwertyuytrxtcfyvgubhkvjchxye56udb4sxcbhvutycxt;
Impersonation Level=Impersonate;
catalog=db
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes Full solution it is:

```
        private static string GetAccessToken()
    {
        string clientId = "xxx";
        string aadTenantId = "xxx";
        string clientSecretKey = "xxx";

        string AadInstance = "https://login.windows.net/{0}";
        string ResourceId = "https://northeurope.asazure.windows.net/"; //Be careful it must be your resource location. please find it on your azure service. Otherwise you can take token but you cannot login your service.

        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(AadInstance, aadTenantId));
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecretKey);

        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceId, clientCredential).Result;

        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
```

And use it :

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var accessToken = GetAccessToken();

        var server = "asazure://northeurope.asazure.windows.net/yourInstanceName";
        var databaseName = "MY DB NAME";

        string ConnectionString = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source={server};User ID=;Password={accessToken};Catalog={databaseName};Persist Security Info=True; Impersonation Level=Impersonate";

        using (AdomdConnection adomdConnection = new AdomdConnection())
        {
            adomdConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            AdomdCommand adomdCommand = new AdomdCommand();
            adomdCommand.Connection = adomdConnection;                
            adomdCommand.CommandText = "SAMPLE QUERY";
            adomdConnection.Open();
            CellSet cellSet = adomdCommand.ExecuteCellSet();
            adomdConnection.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I need to use managed identity rather than specifying credentials - is this possible?  Thanks

Comment: for Azure Service like Sass. I know we cannot connect with managed identity. Token from login.windows.net always needed.

Answer (score 0):

To use a bearer token with AdomdConnection, format the connection string like this:

```
 var server = ...;
 var token = ...;
 var constr = $"Data Source={server};Password={token};Catalog={database};Persist Security Info=True; Impersonation Level=Impersonate";
```

And the AdomdConnection is *different* than OleDbConnection.  [ADOMD.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/adomd/multidimensional-models-adomd-net-client/adomd-net-client-programming) is the native .NET library for AS/AAS and it's what you should be using.

Comment: See my update, I've replaced the password with the GetToken method but the connection fails

Comment: That doesn't really show how you're acquiring the token.  Are you sure you're getting a token for the resource ID: "https://*.asazure.windows.net" ?

Comment: See updated answer.  Your question title says AdomdConnection, but your code appears to be using OleDbConnection.

Comment: oops thanks, will try again and confirm!  Thank you